# Get Latest on Solution within Visual Studio gets a lot of unnecessary files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

When starting out with a clean environment (nothing downloaded yet) and opening a solution for the first time through the Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio, all the necessary files for the solution are downloaded. Meaning i can compile the solution without any problems.

Then, in Visual Studio, when I do a right-mouse click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and do a "Get Latest", a whole bunch of additional files are downloaded that are part of my TFS tree. These files are not referenced by the solution. Does anybody have any idea why these files are downloaded?

I'm aware of another issue where opening an .sln file will download all the files within its root and subfolders, but that already happens when opening the .sln file through the Source Control explorer. In this particular case the sln file is located in its own subdirectory so this doesn't apply.

I'm would be interested to hear from anybody that has experienced the same thing and has any idea on why all these additional files are downloaded from the TFS tree although they are not referenced by the .sln file and its underlying projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that when you do a *Get Latest Version* within Solution Explorer, under the covers it is performing the operation on the folder that contains the solution and therefore it will pull down any files missing from your local workspace.

If you have items in the solution folder that you don't want to bring down to your local machine then you should use cloaking, explicit mappings and non-recursive mappings to limit what is mapped to your workspace.

[image: Workspace Mappings]

2 = Cloaked, 5 = Non-recursive

[Optimize your workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181378.aspx)

Comment: The sln file is in it owns folder to prevent it from downloading everything from it's own and sub folders. In VS2010 we didn't have this problem, but it seems something has changed in and now testing with VS2013 and VS2015 shows that a whole lof of additional files are downloaded when doing a "Get latest on the solution" in the Solution Explorer. I'm trying to figure out what kind of pattern is being applied to determine what to download and what not, as not everything seems to get downloaded.